# Laravel records not geting as dynamic

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**views/show.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h5>Showing Task {{ $task->title }}</h5>
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
   <p>
      <strong>Task Title:</strong> {{ $task->title }}<br>
      <strong>Description:</strong> {{ $task->description }}
   </p>
</div>
@endsection
```

**Controllers/HomeController.php**

```
public function show(Task $task)
{
   return view('show', compact('task', $task));
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('show/{id}', 'HomeController@show')->name('show');
```

**views/viewalltask.blade.php**

```
<td><a href="{{ route('show', $data->id)}}">{{$data->title}}</a></td>
```

> No error / No Record / instead of particulr record display blank page

Comment: Rename id to task: ```Route::get('show/{task}', 'HomeController@show')->name('show');```

Comment: @ka_lin Add as answer I will upvote

Comment: this should be more simpler  instead of ` return view('show', compact('task', $task)); to 
`  `return view('show', compact('task'));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the route configuration to:

```
Route::get('show/{task}', 'HomeController@show')->name('show');
```

This way Laravel's IOC container knows how to resolve/bind it.

Must match the variable name used in the method definition:

```
public function show(Task $task)
```